# False positives while comparing integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, integer, comparison, compare, operators

I'm facing a really strange problem comparing integer in Javascript. I have an array of numbers and I want to **check if the current number in a loop is smaller than the previous one**. To do so, I save the "current" number as "previous", so I can check them in the next loop. The function runs as expected, EXCEPT every time the current and the previous number have a different number of digits: in this case, the code doesn't see the actually smaller number as being smaller than the previous one.

For example:

```
111 < 120 ? ---> YES!

106 < 111 ? ---> YES!

98 < 106  ? ---> NO!

76 < 98   ? ---> YES!

5 < 76    ? ---> NO!
```

I'm unable to find anything strange in the code I'm using, as it is quite simple:

```
for(var j=0;j<arrScores.length;j++)
{
    if(arrScores[j][0] < scoreAnt)
    {
        console.log("Smaller!");
    }

    scoreAnt = arrScores[j][0];
}
```

I've tried using `parseInt()` in both values, but nothing changes... Checking the length of both numbers using `scoreAnt.toString().length` returns a length of 1, no matter which number it is (100, 34 or 156798), and the same for `arrScores[j][0]`. I've also logged the whole thing to check that the numbers are the expected ones, and they are (the numbers used in the example are some of the ones I'm using)...

Any clue on what can be happening? I'm really lost with this, becuase it makes no sense for me...

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Comment: By the way, you can get around the problem by sorting the array and then taking the first element. This will be the smallest. But of course, that wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: Actually, as the arrays comes sorted, the only thing that could happen aside from being smaller is being the same number: that's why I'm checking it.

Answer (score 1):

You always do `scoreAnt = arrScores[j][0];` in the loop; but you should only do that if arrScores[j] is smaller; i.e. inside the inner curly braces.

```
for(var j=0;j<arrScores.length;j++)
{
    if(arrScores[j][0] < scoreAnt)
    {
        console.log("Smaller!");
        scoreAnt = arrScores[j][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: As the array comes sorted, the j+1 number will surely be smaller or equal to the j number, so updating the "scoreAnt" outside the curly braces shouldn't affect the comparison problem at all (the worst thing it can cause is to update "scoreAnt" to the same number).

Comment: Wait a minute, wait a minute. Sorry for being so blind, but if `arrScores` is the array of numbers, then `arrScores[j]` would be one number, right? Then `arrScores[j][0]` is the _first digit of the number!_ Unless it's a two- (or more-) dimensional array, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: Hi Mr. Lister! Your second bet was right: it's a four-dimensional array hehehe! I can't guess why, but now the function works propoerly... I changed nothing relating the Javascript, so I'm unable to say what was going wrong... We'll say cache problems, for instance! Thanks, though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't even know why, but after changing something relating the CORS of the server where these numbers came from (but not modifying the numbers at all), the comparison seems to work as expected... Have no clue about what might have changed! :S However, now it works correctly...